# Pfsense Multi-wan Access non default gateway

Tags: firewall, port-forwarding, pfsense, gateway

i have a pfsense setup with multiple wan from which they share a gateway group *GW_group1* in the same tier

i have it linked through *tinc* with another 2 setups with the same design and it redirects few ports to other servers and accepts connections from GW_group1 in firewall rules and Direct NAT in the firewall NAT from the interfaces each interface to each of the ports of the servers

```
NAT:
GATEWAY1 PORT 80 -> SERVER 1 PORT 80
GATEWAY2 PORT 80 -> SERVER 1 PORT 80 
GATEWAY1 PORT 90 -> SERVER 2 PORT 90
GATEWAY2 PORT 90 -> SERVER 2 PORT 90

FIREWALL:
ACCEPT GW_group PORT 80 TO SERVER 1 IP ADDRESS
ACCEPT GW_group PORT 90 TO SERVER 2 IP ADDRESS
```

i can get through the firewall from outside if and ONLY IF the connection is coming through the default gateway if i change the default gateway i no longer can access the pfsense nor the servers behind it from outside and get connection timeout even tinc cannot connect unless it's connecting to the default gateway ip address

so if *GATEWAY1* is the default gateway i can access the server through *GATEWAY1* ip but not through *GATEWAY2* ip

can it be solved so that all WANs are accessible from outside at the same time ?

Comment: I think you see the problem from a bad side, usually you need a default gateway, but you can tell some gear to use the gateway #2,  but that mean you do a forward from gw2 to server2

Comment: the problem is that the port forward is not working from non default gateway